# How to monitor and debug every request made to s3 in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, monitor, amazon-cloudtrail

so somehow I've exceeded the 20k allocated monthly requests on the free tier in AWS. in about 7 days.

I was wondering how I can debug this and see where these requests are being made as it seems a hugely successive amount. I have 2 buckets, one where the code lives and one where images live. but images are cached in cloudfront, which should minify the requests made to s3, right?

so I checked cloudtrail but I can't seem to see anywhere that has all the 20k + requests made. is this possible and how do I debug s3 so I can work out where I'm making all these requests

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For you to see in CloudTrail you actually need to [enable it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html) when you create a trail.

This is the same for Lambda API calls.

You can also enable [S3 access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) to see server access logs for requests for S3 objects.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217456/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-williams-how-to-monitor-and-debug-every-request-ma).